# how to print label on Bartende software using java and activeX

Tags: java, printing, activex, barcode-printing

I am working on a project where I need to be able to print label via bartender software. I am planning on doing it with Java but I am not sure how to proceed.  I downloaded the trial version but i cant connect Bartender to my database because it's not SQL Server. But i know that theres a way to send data to bartender so that it can print, but I cannot find the API  and I am having  trouble connecting to them
I know I will have to use ActiveX http://www.bartenderbarcodesoftware.com/label-software/whitepapers/controlling-barcode-label-software-using-activex-automation.pdf .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this tutorial helps, the guy uses BarTender's Commander to make it work with their web app: http://cases.azoft.com/bartender-print-server/

The step-by-step is done for PHP but it's said that the method works with other languages too.